# How to overlay the actionbar after scrolling up view under it?

Tags: android

I want to achieve the animation Like the Google Play app does,i.e. scrolling up the GridView to hide the ActionBar and keep the tabs sticking on top of the screen.
I use [QuickReturn](https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/etiennelawlor/quickreturn/library/listeners/QuickReturnListViewOnScrollListener.java#L55) ,the result:

[image]

The ActionBar is always on the top of the tabs,How can I make it works like a charm as Google Play does.Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try actionBar.hide() ?

Comment: @KetanAhir actionBar.hide() will hide it immediately,I want to hide the actionbar smoothly.

Comment: I think you can implement this by writing **ScrollViewListener** and take the height of your actionbar and actionbartab then show your content (such as listview or cardview) below that height. Then while scrolling along with the content you need to hide actionbar and fix the tab at top of screen. Check out this [link](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) for scrollview listener example and instead of changing the alpha of actionbar you need to hide it! Hope this might help you!